# camel-exec : No endpoint could be found error

Tags: apache-camel

Below is the consumer endpoint. Trying to execute linux/unix command using camel exec process uri.

```
<recipientList>
    <simple>exec:bash?args=-c CFTUTIL SEND IDF=${property[cftFlowIdentifier]}, PART=${property[cftParterName]}, FNAME=${property[cftFullFilePath]}, FNAME=${property[cftDestinationPath]}/${property[cftFileName]}</simple>
</recipientList>
```

Above endpoint resulting in below error..

```
org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: PART=
```

Kindly check if there is anything wrong in invoking above command using camel exec uri. Same command is getting executed successfully in normal java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Recipient List EIP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/recipientList-eip.html) accepts comma separated list of endpoints. If you need to use comma in URL, then disable or use another delimiter.

```
<recipientList delimiter="false">
   <simple>...</simple>
</recipientList>
```

---

You can also switch to [To D EIP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/toD-eip.html), which is more suitable for your needs, as you call just one endpoint.

```
<toD uri="exec:bash?args=-c CFTUTIL SEND IDF=${property[cftFlowIdentifier]}, PART=${property[cftParterName]}, FNAME=${property[cftFullFilePath]}, FNAME=${property[cftDestinationPath]}/${property[cftFileName]}"/>
```